# Is the comparison matrix of a P-matrix again a P-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a [P-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20P%2Dmatrix,0.). Is the [comparison matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_matrix) of $A$ again a P-matrix? Why/why not?

I have a feeling this might be the case and it would help me greatly if it was, but i don't know if it's true and why/why not. And i couldn't find anything about it either.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1 & 10 \\ -10 & 1},
$$
with $\det A=101$, but the comparison matrix of $A$ is
$$
\pmatrix{1 & -10 \\ -10 & 1},
$$
which has determinant $-99$. So $A$ is P-matrix, but its comparison matrix not.